# How to set isDirty() value dynamically in Ext Js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how to set isDirty() value dynamically in Ext Js

I have form panel which contains textbox, radio buttons and save button. In afterrender function i am setting a value to textbox . after loading the page the isDirty() is returning true, but my requirement is when I click on update button only it should return true.

how I can achieve this.

I tried with trackResetOnLoad= true but its not working.

Fiddle example is 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1d74

Update:-
I need track Change or update  after Afterrender function.

Comment: There is no radio button. Also why you given isDirty button. If I am not wrong then here you need only update button.

Comment: Its just sample program. isDirty button will just alert isDirty() value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same functionality by giving ***value*** config to textfield rather than setting anything in afterrender. When you run the below code , you will not get true in **isDirty** button when you first click it.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var form = new Ext.form.Panel({
        itemId:'panelFormID',
        trackResetOnLoad: true,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield'
            ,name: 'username'
            ,itemId : 'username'
            ,fieldLabel: 'username'
           , value:'stackoverflow'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield'
            ,name: 'password'
             ,itemId : 'password'
            ,fieldLabel: 'password'

        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text : 'isDirty' ,handler: function() {
                alert(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].isDirty());
            }},
            {
            xtype: 'button',
            text : 'Update' ,
            handler: function() {
                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#username')[0].setValue ('resetvalue');
         Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#password')[0].setValue ('restpassword');
            }
        }]


    }
    })
```

;

});

Comment: Thanks @Sallo for your answer. In After render function i will get the value from DB and will set value to TextBox. I need use SetValue function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form component's setValues method for this purpose. This couldn't change your dirty status while your form's trackResetOnLoad property is true.

In your case you can do it like that;

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].up('form').getForm().setValues({
                username : 'reset value',
                password : 'resetpassword'
            });
```

These object properties related with your component's name property. When you miss some field's value it gonna set as empty. so you have to get all of it's value and change your wishes and set again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your afterrender listener:

```
var items = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')    [0].getForm().getFields().items,
  i = 0,
  len = items.length;
for(; i < len; i++) {
var c = items[i];
if(c.mixins && c.mixins.field && typeof c.mixins.field['initValue'] == 'function') {
  c.mixins.field.initValue.apply(c);
  c.wasDirty = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isDirty() depends upon **originalValue** of respective component.In afterrender as you set value to field, you also need to set originalValue field.I have added this line in afterrender code:

```
        afterrender :function () {
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#username')[0].setValue ('stackoverflow');
        //new line
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#username')[0].originalValue='stackoverflow'

        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].trackResetOnLoad = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this after setting values (in afterrender function):

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].form.setValues(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#panelFormID')[0].form.getValues())
```